# Weirdness with dates in Javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb, date

I am storing date objects in mongodb. When I fetch them out, I get something like this:

```
"2016-10-18T10:53:31.851Z"
```

When I take that string and put it into a date function I get this:

```
Date("2016-10-18T10:53:31.851Z")
"Fri Nov 18 2016 14:15:44 GMT-0500 (EST)"
```

Note that the minutes and the seconds, and even the month looks incorrect. The hour looks like it is off by one. Why is that?

Comment: "Z" means Zulu time (UTC).

Comment: You are calling *Date* as a function, not as a constructor. When called as a function, it doesn't take any arguments and just returns a string representing the current date and time in an implementation dependent format. See [*20.3.2The Date Constructor*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-date-constructor): "*When Date is called as a function rather than as a constructor, it returns a String representing the current time (UTC).*". The "UTC" part was added with ECMAScript 2016, so not all implementations comply.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

invoking Date in the way you are doing produces the current date and time. To create a variable based on that string, use

```
new Date("2016-10-18T10:53:31.851Z")
Tue Oct 18 2016 03:53:31 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
```